# Java class version of C#'s Dictionary<key, value>

Tags: c#, java, dictionary

I'm working on converting a C# program to a Java program. Is there a class in Java comparable in usage to C#'s

```
Dictionary<key, value> dictionary = new Dictionary<key, value>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Dictionary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) abstract class in Java, which has a single direct subclass - [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html).

But in the javadoc is clearly said:

> This class is obsolete. New implementations should implement the
>   Map interface, rather than extending this class.

A sample Map:

```
Map<Key, Value> map = new HashMap<Key,Value>();
```

Note that [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is an interface and [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is an implementation of `Map`. There are many other `Map` imeplementations, like [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), [IdentityHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html), etc. Which implementation to use depends on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is likely what you want.

Hashtable is synchronized; it works more reliably across multiple threads, but for most code, HashMap.

Kocko nails it, above.